# 3rd party IDP with B2B signup flow

Tags: idp, azure-ad-b2b

Is it possible to attach a 3rd party IDP with an Azure AD B2B self signup flow? I am able to attach Google and FB but not an enterprise 3rd party IDP that I created.

Is it something which cannot be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [direct federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation) with any organization whose identity provider (IdP) supports the SAML 2.0 or WS-Fed protocol.

The allowed [identity providers list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation#authentication-url):

- accounts.google.com
- pingidentity.com
- login.pingone.com
- okta.com
- oktapreview.com
- okta-emea.com
- my.salesforce.com
- federation.exostar.com
- federation.exostartest.com

More details on [Azure AD B2B collaboration direct federation with SAML and WS-Fed providers](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/azure-ad-b2b-collaboration-direct-federation-with-saml-and-ws/ba-p/735133).

Comment: Federation is setup and the users are able to authenticate against the IDP. My question is - can self-service signup feature be used with the 3rd party IDP? I couldn't find any way to attach the IDP to the user flow.

Comment: @SushmitaDas So this issue is resolved right? If my answer is correct, you can accept it. Thank you:)

Comment: My question is different. I want to know if a self service flow for B2B can be configured using 3rd party IDP. "Is it possible to attach a 3rd party IDP with an Azure AD B2B self signup flow? I am able to attach Google and FB but not an enterprise 3rd party IDP that I created.

Is it something which cannot be done?"

Comment: @SushmitaDas The supported ready-made solution are Google and FB currently. No other 3rd party IDP options. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow